# How do I get the F1-F12 keys to switch screens in gnu screen in cygwin when connecting via SSH?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, gnu-screen

I'm connecting to a desktop running cygwin via SSH from the terminal app in Mac OS X.  I have already started screen on the cygwin side and can connect to it over the SSH session.  Furthermore, I have the following in the .screenrc file:

```
bindkey -k k1 select 1  #  F1 = screen 1
bindkey -k k2 select 2  #  F2 = screen 2
bindkey -k k3 select 3  #  F3 = screen 3
bindkey -k k4 select 4  #  F4 = screen 4
bindkey -k k5 select 5  #  F5 = screen 5
bindkey -k k6 select 6  #  F6 = screen 6
bindkey -k k7 select 7  #  F7 = screen 7
bindkey -k k8 select 8  #  F8 = screen 8
bindkey -k k9 select 9  #  F9 = screen 9
bindkey -k F1 prev      # F11 = prev
bindkey -k F2 next      # F12 = next
```

However, when I start multiple windows in screen and attempt to switch between them via the function keys, all I get is a beep.

I have tried various settings for $TERM (e.g. ansi, cygwin, xterm-color, vt100) and they don't really seem to affect anything.

I have verified that the terminal app is in fact sending the escape sequence for the function key that I'm expecting and that my bash shell (running inside screen) is receiving it.  For example, for F1, it sends the following (hexdump is a perl script I wrote that takes STDIN in binmode and outputs it as a hexadecimal/ascii dump):

```
% hexdump
[press F1 and then hit ^D to terminate input]
00000000:  1b4f50                               .OP
```

If things were working correctly, I don't think bash should receive the escape sequence because screen should have caught it and turned it into a command.

How do I get the function keys to work?

Comment: The FAQ says: "software tools commonly used by programmers".  The tools I described seem relevant to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a great deal of experimentation, I was able to get it to work by adding the following lines to my .screenrc:

```
terminfo * k1=\EOP
terminfo * k2=\EOQ
terminfo * k3=\EOR
terminfo * k4=\EOS
terminfo * k5=\E[15~
terminfo * k6=\E[17~
terminfo * k7=\E[18~
terminfo * k8=\E[19~
terminfo * k9=\E[20~
terminfo * F1=\E[23~
terminfo * F2=\E[24~
```

Comment: It would be nice if you showed the method you used to arrive at this solution. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't remember it clearly as it was a couple of years ago.  Part of it had to do with knowing the terminal names for the keys (e.g. k1, k2, etc.) and part of it had to do with knowing what your terminal transmits when you hit F1, F2, etc.

I was able to figure out the latter by running "read" in the bash shell and then hitting F1, F2, etc.  For example, when I run read and hit F1, this is what I saw:

`% read
^[OP
`

Comment: In bash, if you hit Ctrl-V followed by the function key of interest, then you will visually see the above codes printed on the command line. This is how you find the codes. Maybe it's a `readline` feature?

Answer (score 20):

If you have a more bizarre setup (e.g. Windows -> PuTTY -> Linux) where the standard `bindkey -k` solution doesn't quite work right, you can use the `showkey` command:

```
showkey -a
```

to find the mapping from keystrokes to key codes.  In my particular case, putting these in `~/.screenrc` did the trick:

```
bindkey "^[[11~" select 1
bindkey "^[[12~" select 2
bindkey "^[[13~" select 3
bindkey "^[[14~" select 4
bindkey "^[[15~" select 5
bindkey "^[[17~" select 6
bindkey "^[[18~" select 7
bindkey "^[[19~" select 8
bindkey "^[[20~" select 9
bindkey "^[[21~" select 10
bindkey "^[[23~" select 11
bindkey "^[[24~" select 12
```

Comment: I have a similiar "weird" setup using mobaxterm. First I disabled the mobaxterm shortcut for f11 and then I still had F10 not working with bindkey -k Fx (F1 is F11, F2 is F12 but F0 doesn't work, perhaps it's hexadecimal). Anyway I used your solution to get the correct bindkey value for F10. Thanks.

Comment: This works for me on mac os with external magic keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using iTerm on macos. This works for me:

```
terminfo * F1=^[OP
terminfo * F2=^[OQ

bindkey -k F1 prev
bindkey -k F2 next
```

Put these 4 lines in your .screenrc.

Answer inspired by Mikey's answer.